# PasteSpecial error when cutting instead of copying

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "calendar" and sometimes I have "tasks" (with comments) that I want to move to a different date on the calendar.  I can do it successfully (keeping the comment) but then I have to go back and delete the original location.  When I try the following with ctrl-x instead of ctrl-c, I get an error `PasteSpecial method of range class failed` on the first PasteSpecial call

```
Sub PasteasValue()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Call ShapeThem(Selection)

    Application.EnableEvents = True


End Sub
```

I'm not sure what is fundamentally different when I cut vs copy.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: The first paste special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste Special only works with copy, and not cut. You can't do this manually either.

If you comment out the first Paste Special, the second one will fail too.

Comment: Ok; do you know a way to cut and paste while preserving the comment?

Comment: You'd have to use the normal paste instead of pastespecial (so you can't just keep values, you'll get formats too).